# What permissions do I need to get Connections API?

Tags: linkedin-api

Currently I log in

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id[myclientid]&state=invite&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8081&scope=r_basicprofile+rw_company_admin+w_share

Then I make an OAuth GET request in Postman

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?code[accesstokengivenfrompreviousrequest]&client_secret[mysecretclient]&client_id[myclientid]&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8081&grant_type=authorization_code

And then I make a GET request in Postman for my connections like the example they gave me [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api)

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&count=50

and these are my results

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode":100,
    "message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections",
    "status":403
}
```

The page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api) says:

> "To use the Connections API, you must request an access token to make
>   an authenticated call on behalf of a member."

and the permissions given are: `r_1st_connections` & `r_compliance` so when I try to add those permissions to the first login link I posted, it says it's not in the scope of what I can do. So I try to look for what I need for these [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/permissions?context=linkedin/context) and follow to [2-legged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context) and [3-legged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) permissions page where it states none of the permissions or what is needed for them.

So how do I access `r_1st_connections` & `r_compliance`?

And to save me trouble, because if you know that then you would probably know whether or not I can obtain an email addresses from my `r_1st_connections`, because if I can't then I don't need to bother with this anyways.

Comment: I have this issue as well. There is no information anywhere on how to apply for scopes such as ''r_1st_connections"

Comment: Hey @Raults, did you find out how to get connections API approve?